# What should we do with low quality posts from new users who can't leave comments?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues, low-quality-posts, new-users

While reviewing Low Quality Posts we always see posts made by low reputation users who can't leave a comment, So:

[image]

- Is it fair to flag those posts as Low Quality Posts?
- Is it fair to recommend deletion, as **This is commentary on another
  post, not an answer** ?

Because some posts are entending to help or to provide the OP with answers or suggestions, and if these users aren't allowed to comment, aren't we excluding and deprivating them from their right to contribute in the site?

Comment: That is such a half-baked comment, even if well meaning, I doubt it helps anyone. If it would indeed be really helpful it could be written up as a proper answer and nobody would have any issue with it at all.

Comment: I just took this as an example.

Comment: That closevote is incorrect. This question isn't about the _"Not an answer"_ Flag, but about the _"Low quality"_ one instead.

Comment: Why is everybody downvoting?

Comment: @chsdk: [Voting on meta.SO is different than on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: @Cerbrus yes I know that downvoting will not affect my reputation, but I thought it whould deride the question, Thanks anyway.

Comment: I guess the votes indicate the opinion that we shouldn't do anything differently. I see these low quality posts all the time so its definitely a problem, and its awkward telling users that they should comment instead (or hold off entirely until they have that privilege) when you know they can't. That said, I don't see a good solution - those posts should be removed asap!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To answer both your questions:

- *Is it fair to flag those posts as Low Quality Posts?*
- *Is it fair to recommend deletion, as This is commentary on another post, not an answer?*

***Yes it is.***
The fact that the user has a low amount of rep doesn't change the rules they should adhere to.

It only [takes 50 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) to be able to comment everywhere. That amount isn't that hard to gain, just one or two decent answers should be plenty to meet the requirement.

Comment: While you're right I think one should always keep in mind that this page is for answering questions as good as possible - if something gets people to learn to answer questions better the effort was worth it. Just deleting it will only create frustration, not improve the overall quality in the long run.

Comment: How will deleting bad posts not improve the overall quality of SE's contents in the long run? The effort required to be able to comment is negligible. A user that isn't willing or patient enough to do that, shouldn't get treated any differently than any other user on SO.

Comment: Getting people to realize why their post and maybe get better posts from them in the future is the higher priority in my point of view. Just deleting is frustrating, rewriting might help them get better themselves.

Comment: There's no reason not to get rid of bad posts. If a more experienced user feels it's worth his time, he can give some advice to the new user. How would you suggest the post linked in the OP should be rewritten? I don't see how it's salvageable. Even as a comment, it's mediocre.

Comment: As I said, it's not that you're not right.

Comment: Yes, we need to get rid of bad posts, but a least we need to explain for those users why their posts are being deleted and advise them to improve their posts.

Comment: @chsdk: No. Users don't _have_ to comment when down / close-voting. Comments aren't mandatory.

Comment: Yes I know that it's not mandatory, but just to show these users the reason why their posts are being deleted.

Comment: And the screenshot in your question has exactly that, a comment with a reason the post is being downvoted / removed. So what's the problem?

Comment: A comment that says `leave a comment below their post`, while they **can't leave a comment**!

Comment: Which can be solved by earning some more rep

Comment: But it *says* so in the stock comment: ***once you have sufficient reputation***. The text is in blue, meaning it is (most likely) a hyperlink, and all that is asked of them is to click the link!

Comment: @chsdk It's not like such things aren't explained *anywhere*. Those users could very easily figure it out if they were so inclined. Why is the onus always on the community to repeat the same indoctrination message to everyone personally over and over?

Comment: @deceze Yes you are right, I just thought that not allowing those users to comment and deleting their posts whould be a deprivation, but finally rules are rules.

Comment: @Gnat: Please don't change that link. I meant to link to the "Commenting" __privilege__. Not to some question / answer that explains how to earn your first 50 rep. Users that need to know how to earn rep aren't likely to see this question any way.